# buy a stock during stock split

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I see the following statement:

"BELLINGHAM, Wash. — Jan. 19, 2021 — eXp World Holdings, Inc. (Nasdaq: EXPI), today announced that its Board of Directors has approved a 2-for-1 stock split in the form of a stock dividend to make stock ownership more accessible to employees and investors. Each stockholder of record on Jan. 29, 2021 will receive one additional share of common stock for each then-held share, which will be distributed after the close of trading on Feb. 12, 2021. eXp World Holdings common stock will begin trading on a stock split-adjusted basis on Feb. 16, 2021."

If I buy the stock today, what will happen? Will I get another share after Feb. 12th? Or, the value of my share will be slashed to half after Feb. 12th?

Comment: There are scores of questions and answers here that explain a stock split (duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

You know when you have **a $20 note, and you change it for two $10 notes**.

It is ***exactly like that.***

Your one share (price, say $70) will become two shares (price, say $35 each).

There is absolutely no difference, whatsoever.

Assuming this is the normal, usual type of stock split that is exactly what will happen.

Comment: But in the statement, it said "Each stockholder of record on Jan. 29, 2021 will receive one additional share of common stock for each then-held share". Then, why does it say the date "Jan. 29, 2021" if it does not matter whether I buy the stock on Jan. 29, 2021 or on Feb. 8th 2021?

Comment: If you buy AFTER the split, you are buying the "NEW SMALLER ONES".  Say you have $70 to spend.  BEFORE the split you will buy ONE. (1 x 70).  AFTER the split you will simply buy TWO (2 x 35). Does it make sense?